# use two php versions(v7.2, v5.6) without create of subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, subdomain, cpanel

I have to upgrade my website in Laravel which is using PHP 7.2 and point root directory(public_html). 
In root(public_html) directory I have a folder "portal" which is a separate module in Codeigniter which is using PHP 5.6

Is there any way so I can apply **PHP 7.2** on root folder(public_html) and **PHP 5.6** in **portal** folder only .

like
http://www.webiste.com/   **work with PHP7.2**

http://www.webiste.com/portal   **work with PHP5.6**

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE is the exact code

**Put this code in bottom of your .htaccess file in sub domain folder**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
     AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

**Put this code in bottom of your .htaccess file of "public_html" folder**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.htaccess` file in each folder and specify the php handler (in a specified php version) by using `AddHandler`:

**/.htaccess**

```
# PHP 7.2
AddHandler x-httpd-php72 .php
```

**/portal/.htaccess**

```
# PHP 5.6
AddHandler x-httpd-php56 .php
```

Answer (score 0):

Php file content display instead of running code ? , using this method

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```